# Add multiple test cases in Verilog test bench

Tags: verilog, testbench

I am working with a Verilog test bench which needs multiple test cases to be added to it.

How can I add multiple testcase files (approximate 8 test cases) to the test bench (by using package, import, include concept)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic methodology question that involves defining a testbench architecture that can accept multiple test cases. And before you can do that, you need a precise definition that distinguishes between a *test architecture* and a *test case*.

The testbench architecture, like the design architecture, gets elaborated before time zero and cannot be changed once the simulation has started. You can only group test cases together within a common architecture.

The test case becomes the procedural steps of generating stimulus and checking results. This can be encapsulated is one or more concurrently executing tasks.
In the simplest form, a testcase can be enclosed in a task, and you can call each task in series from a top-level modules.

The [UVM espouses a standard methodology](https://verificationacademy.com/courses/uvm-basics) for defining the testbench architecture in the form of class-based components, and test cases in the form of class-based sequences.

A few things you need to consider when putting test cases in a series

- the design needs to be properly reset. You don't want anything in progress from the previous test to affect the current test
- If there is an error in a test, should you stop the remaining tests, or is there a recovery or rest required?
- Running tests in series lengthens the turn-around time. You will to be able to take advantage of parallel compute resources.